# Creating bash for systemd running background

Tags: bash, systemd, selinux

I am trying to write a script to log the change in MySQL table:
`/home/user/trigger_systemd/check_db1.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqloption='--defaults-extra-file=/home/user/.mycnf/local_root.cnf'

lastUpdate_0=$(mysql $mysqloption -N db1 -e "SELECT DATE(lastUpdate) FROM db1.lastUpdate")
lastUpdate_1=$(mysql $mysqloption -N db1 -e "SELECT DATE(lastUpdate) FROM db1.lastUpdate")

#echo $lastUpdate_0

while :
do
        while [ $lastUpdate_0 == $lastUpdate_1 ]
        do
                lastUpdate_1=$(mysql $mysqloption -N db1 -e "SELECT DATE(lastUpdate) FROM db1.lastupdate")
                #echo $lastUpdate_1
                sleep 20
        done
        echo $(date) ": " $lastUpdate_0 " -> " $lastUpdate_1 >> /home/user/trigger_systemd/trial.log
        lastupdate_0=$lastupdate_1
done
```

And here is my service script:
`/etc/systemd/system/trial_monitor.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=monitor trial
After=mysqld.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/trigger_systemd/check_db1.bash
PIDFile=/tmp/check_db1.pid
#Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it keep give me fail result:

```
● trial_monitor.service - monitor trial
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/trial_monitor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-08-30 09:04:27 HKT; 3s ago
  Process: 2001631 ExecStart=/home/user/trigger_systemd/check_db1.bash (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 2001631 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 30 09:04:27 ****.localdomain systemd[1]: Started monitor trial.
Aug 30 09:04:27 ****.localdomain systemd[1]: trial_monitor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 30 09:04:27 ****.localdomain systemd[1]: trial_monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have tried to run directly and it success, what's wrong with my writing?

The system runs with **SELinux**.
If it is the root cause for the fail, how to make it works?

Comment: Did you `chmod +x` your script? Does `findmnt -T /home/user -u` show 'noexec' anywhere in the options field?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472950/systemd-status-203-exec-error-when-creating-new-service) answer your question?